# Cannot access server after application deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, vpn

At first i deployed a Java application in an app server running on JBoss. When i tried to hit the application URL, the application wouldn't be accessible and when pinging also, the server didn't reply. But sometimes, the application would run(server was also accessible). Then i migrated to Tomcat,same issue. Later i changed the server(physical machine), but same issue persists. What could be the reason for occasional network disruption ? Is it the application itself, or the VPN network  ? (I access those servers via VPN). Please suggest.

Comment: You should need to check your war file is deployed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your network configurations but try these things:

1. Firewall settings on your server.
2. Port exposed (80 or 8080).
3. If you think it is vpn or network issue then ask someone who is sitting in that network to access your application.
4. Launch server in debug mode.
5. Look into the logs if your server or application to see if some error is being reported.

These will be my first steps.

Thanks,
Prateek